# How to write a DAX formula on an RLS SSAS?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, powerbi, dax, ssas

I have a data model that is like this:

[image]

Joins are done between tables on storenumber and storename.

I would like to give access to the stores staff but they only see the sales of their own store. I added their mail in the table Y2_Stores.

The sales data are in the table Y2_Sales.

In analysis services I added a role "Stores" in read, in Membership I added the email addresses of the stores, on the line filters I put that but I see in the microsoft documentation that it is necessary to make a formula with the functions LOOKUPVALUE() and USERNAME() but I do not know how to build this formula..

I tried this formula in Y2_Sales line:

```
=Y2_Sales[storenumber]=LOOKUPVALUE(Y2_Stores[storenumber],
Y2_Stores[email], USERNAME(),
Y2_Stores[storenumber],
Y2_Sales[detail_number])
```

I tried this too:

```
Y2_Stores[email] = USERPRINCIPALNAME()
```

[image]

Can you help me to write the correct DAX formula?
Thanks a lot

**UPDATE** :

I added the Y2_StoreEmployee table with storenumber | email and made a relation on storenumber in double direction to the Y2_Stores table :

[image]

Relationships:

[image]

I created a role with this formula:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There should be a table related to Store, eg StoreEmployee, with (StoreNumber,Email), configured for bidirectional cross filtering with Store.  Then the RLS filter filter is on StoreEmployee and is just `Email=USERPRINCIPALNAME()`.

So each user sees only their own rows in StoreEmployee, that creates a filter that propagates to Store, and then to the Sales, Inventory, and Images.

Comment: I updated my question, I did what you told me but when I connect with the email I put in the Y2_StoreEmployee table I still see all the sales... is there anything else to do?

Comment: I tried to refresh my database but still see all the sales

Comment: Start with an trivial model and get that working first.  Make sure you know how to test RLS by creating a measure displaying the USERPRINCIPALNAME() and using EffectiveUserName (or the Modeling > View As dialog in PBI Desktop).

Comment: I had made a Power Bi report using the userprincipalname() measure and it returned my email fine. Now I have to deploy it on a services analysis model, but I don't understand why it doesn't work with your explanations... what else can I check?

Comment: Why not just deploy it to Power BI?  Do your RLS rules work when testing in Power BI Desktop?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, my model is necessarily in analysis services, constraint of my company. So I use Power BI desktop only to build the report but the measures and RLS must be in analysis services and then I deploy on the app.powerbi to give access to users

Comment: I will try to open the report with Power Bi desktop by connecting with the email address of a store

Comment: To test RLS with Analysis Services connect as an SSAS admin using the EffectiveUsername connection string parameter.

Comment: I connect to the server with SSMS with my email address + password (admin account) and in the connection options I add "EffectiveUsername" ?